# Downside on not using Ionic components in mobile app

Tags: ionic-framework, vue.js, ionic4

I am creating a mobile application using vuejs and ionic capacitor. I am not able to use v-model to bind to ION components it looks like I am able to use regular HTML components such as input and button

```
<ion-input type="text" :value="email" @input="email = $event.target.value" placeholder="Username"></ion-input>
```

vs

```
  <input type="text" v-model ="username" placeholder="Username"></ion-input>
```

Apart from having to craft the styling myself, is there any other downside I am missing. The app appears to run fine on native ios and Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the Ionic read.me on their alpha release, the support for v-model is work-in-process. So, no v-model on Ionic components for the moment.